# Unfamiliar error: ActionController::RoutingError at /show uninitialized constant UserController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /show

uninitialized constant UserController
```

I have checked my routes, and controller several times and they seem fine so I will post them below

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:image, :name)
  end
 end
```

the route:

```
get 'index' => 'users#index'
get 'show' => 'user#show'
```

the attempted link to the show page from the index view:

```
<h4 class="media-heading"><%= link_to user.name, show_path %></h4>
```

Thanks for the help, will gladly post more info if needed.

Comment: You need to change `get 'show' => 'user#show'` to `get 'show' => 'users#show'`. Notice the plural form.

Comment: Resourceful ruotes are a preferred way for routes like that. You could have made the same with `resources :users, only: [:index, :show]` and avoid this error altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have an error in routes:

`get 'show' => 'user#show'` should be `get 'show', to: 'users#show'`

2. You don't have `show` action in your controller
3. I would use RESTful routes, which is simply:

`resources :users` # this will generate routes for you

You can specify which actions you want, or which you want to restrict using `only` or `except` options as @D-Side says in comments